# Amazon EC2 permissions and a simple web server

Tags: amazon-ec2, webserver

I just started experiment with EC2 tonight, and got a server running locally.  I know it works locally because when I curl http://localhost:8080/hello it outputs hello.

I want to access this from the outside world.  I modified my permissions in my security group to allow 8080 access, and then typed in "curl http://ec2-123-45-67-891.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/hello" into my local terminal.  I got the response "curl: (7) couldn't connect to host".

Do I need to do something differently?  (Obviously yes, but what?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allowed access on 8080, but in your localhost example, it's running on port 80.

Comment: Eric, I just read your article here: http://alestic.com/2009/08/ec2-connectivity  I went through the list of things to check and don't see what I'm doing wrong.  I should add that this is a custom Linux server where the only thing I've installed is the Python Bottle framework.  My security group is set with ports 22, 80, and 8080 set to "0.0.0.0/0".

Answer (score 2):

Have you bound your server only to localhost?  If so, you'll only be able to connect from localhost.

Check the netstat output for your process with something like:

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep your_server_process
```

Look for whether your server process is bound to 127.0.0.1:8080 or 0.0.0.0:8080.  If the former, then you're only bound to localhost and you need to reconfigure it.

Comment: and what if you're on 0.0.0.0:8080 ? how can you tunnel or port-forward so that you can access it from  http://ec2-123-45-67-891.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/ (url from above) ? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue. Try use 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.